# Using Tidyr/Dplyr to summarise counts of groups of strings

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to summarise the counts of strings I am assigning to groups, and I know I can do it in dplyr/tidyr but I am missing something.

Example dataset:

```
Owner = c('bob','julia','cheryl','bob','julia','cheryl')
Day = c('Mon', 'Tue') 
Locn = c('house','store','apartment','office','house','shop')
data <- data.frame(Owner, Day, Locn)
```

which looks like this:

```
   Owner Day      Locn
1    bob Mon     house
2  julia Tue     store
3 cheryl Mon apartment
4    bob Tue    office
5  julia Mon     house
6 cheryl Tue      shop
```

I want to group by name and day, and then count up grouped locations in columns. In this example I want 'house' and 'apartment' to add to a column titled 'Home', and 'store', 'office' and 'shop' to be counted in a column 'Work'.

My current code (which doesn't work):

```
grouped_locn <- data %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Owner, Day) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Owner, Day) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Home = which(data$Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment')), 
               Work = which(data$Locn %in% c("store", "office", "apartment")))
```

I have only included my current attempt at the summarize step to show how I have been approaching it. The Home and Work code currently returns vectors of the row numbers that contain an element of the group (ie Home = 1 3 5)

My intended output:

```
   Owner Day   Home  Work
1    bob Mon      1     0
2    bob Tue      0     1
3  julia Mon      1     0
4  julia Tue      0     1
5 cheryl Mon      1     0
6 cheryl Tue      0     1
```

In the actual dataset (30k+ rows) there are multiple Locn values per Owner per Day, so the Home and Work counts can be numbers other than 1 and 0 (so no booleans).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
data %>%
  group_by(Owner, Day) %>%
  summarise(Home = sum(Locn %in% c("house", "apartment")), 
            Work = sum(Locn %in% c("store", "office", "shop")))
```

Comment: Hnn... I was sure I had tried that. Does using data$Locn instead of Locn after summarize mess up the function? It works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I guess so. `Locn` respects the grouping, `data$Locn` does not.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an easy and efficient solution using `data.table`

For older versions (v < 1.9.5)

```
library(data.table) # v < 1.9.5
setDT(data)[, Locn2 := c("Work", "Home")[(Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment')) + 1L]]
dcast.data.table(data, Owner + Day ~ Locn2, length)
#     Owner Day Home Work
# 1:    bob Mon    1    0
# 2:    bob Tue    0    1
# 3: cheryl Mon    1    0
# 4: cheryl Tue    0    1
# 5:  julia Mon    1    0
# 6:  julia Tue    0    1
```

---

For newer versions (v >= 1.9.5) you can do this in one line

```
dcast(setDT(data), Owner + Day ~ c("Work", "Home")[(Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment')) + 1L], length)
```

---

Here's a `tidyr` alternative

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(temp = 1L, 
         Locn = ifelse(Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment'), "Home", "Work")) %>% 
  spread(Locn, temp, fill = 0L)

#    Owner Day Home Work
# 1    bob Mon    1    0
# 2    bob Tue    0    1
# 3 cheryl Mon    1    0
# 4 cheryl Tue    0    1
# 5  julia Mon    1    0
# 6  julia Tue    0    1
```

Comment: Ok, added a `tidyr` alternative (as you mentioned it in the question).

Comment: Not from me! I definitely like your solutions, and I am going to look into dcast because it seems pretty flexible. Cheers

Comment: Can I start getting explanations for the downvotes on this answer in particular?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
data[c('Work', 'Home')] <- model.matrix(~0+indx, transform(data, 
       indx =  Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment')))

   data
 #   Owner Day      Locn Work Home
 #1    bob Mon     house    0    1
 #2  julia Tue     store    1    0
 #3 cheryl Mon apartment    0    1
 #4    bob Tue    office    1    0
 #5  julia Mon     house    0    1
 #6 cheryl Tue      shop    1    0
```

Or

```
 library(qdapTools)
 data[c('Work', 'Home')] <- mtabulate(data$Locn %in% c('house', 'apartment'))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is like @lukeA proposed solution, but using the `grepl` function:

```
library(dplyr)

data %<>% arrange(Owner, Day) %>% group_by(Owner, Day) %>%
  summarise(Home=sum((grepl("house|apartment", Locn))*1), 
            Work=sum((grepl("store|office|shop", Locn))*1))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at grep too, but I was sure I could do it with %in%