# How to group by factor levels from two columns and output new column that shows sum of each level in R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataframe that consists of 4 columns: ID, Date(m/d/y), Renewal, Year. I need to group by ID, Renewal per year and sum the number of renewals. From there I will calculate retention rate for each ID based on 2016, 2017, and 2018. Reference df below generated from this code:

```
Account_Type <- complete_df %>%
  group_by(ID, Raw_DATE, Renewal)


ID  Raw_DATE               Renewal               YEAR
1   6/3/2017               LOST                 2017
1   7/12/2018              WON                  2018
1   10/2/2016              LOST                 2016
1   1/26/2016              LOST                 2016
2   6/27/2017              WON                  2017
2   10/3/2016              LOST                 2016
2   12/1/2018              WON                  2018
2   11/15/2017             LOST                 2017
```

My desired output should look something like above but now it grouped by year, and each ID contains sum of "Won" and "Lost" values:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr / tidyr - Summarise data with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565522/dplyr-tidyr-summarise-data-with-conditions) That shows you the tidy way. The base R options include recoding (e.g. `t$Renewal <- ifelse(t$Renewal == "WON", 1, 0)`) then using `aggregate`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping by 'RawDate', group by 'ID', 'YEAR' and get the `sum` on a logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
complete_df %>%
       group_by(ID, YEAR) %>%
       mutate(TotalWon = sum(Renewal == 'WON'), TotalLost = sum(Renewal == 'LOST'))
```

If we need a summarised output, use `summarise` instead of `mutate`