# R Studio - group by dataframe and get statistics using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

[image]

I want to group by "ID" and "direction", then get the statistics for "value". The hardest thing for me is that for "category" column, I need to always output the last "category" in "ID" group, as highlighted on the picture.

I have the code, but the result is not desirable. Can anyone please help me to modify the existing code? Thank you for your time!

```
ID        <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
category  <- c("green", "green", "red", "red","green", "green", "yellow", "yellow")
direction <- c("in", "out","in", "out","in", "out","in", "out")
value     <- c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
df        <- data.frame(ID, category, direction, value)

res <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID,direction) %>% 
  arrange(ID, direction)%>%
  summarize(
    category    = last(category),
    sum_value   = sum(value),
    count_value = length(value)
  )
```

Comment: Please review this and if it doesn't answer your question please describe the difference and what is meant by "I have the code, but the result is not desirable"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565522/dplyr-tidyr-summarise-data-with-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. It's just that your "last(category)" grouping is based only on ID rather than both ID and direction. If you change it to:

```
res <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(category = last(category)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(ID, direction, category) %>% 
  summarise(
    sum_value = sum(value),
    count_value = length(value)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the result is what I want. Can you explain what does "ungroup" mean because the result is same when I delete it. Also, what does "mutate" add to the code?

Comment: `ungroup` does basically what it says on the tin, i.e. it ungroups the data.frame. If you wanted to use res further in your code it would still be grouped, which could cause unexpected effects due to the dplyr verbs acting on the grouped dfs rather than the whole df. `mutate` keeps all columns whereas `summarise` just keeps the grouping columns and the ones you've added inside the `summarise` call.